# Jmeter automatically add "/" in the path

Tags: json, jmeter

I created, with jmeter, two requests.
The first one gives me, a json containing an URL.
I parse this json to grab the URL and transfer it to the second request.

My problem is that jmeter automatically add a slash to the path of the second request, I don't want/need it and it makes my application crash (The / is not present in the URL in the json).

I tries to set a defined variable empty_path with empty value and add the variable in the path but jmeter still add the slash at the end of the URL.

Do you have an idea to avoid this / ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you show your config and the URLs

Answer (score 0):

maybe add a null charachter encoded in HTML code like %20

Answer (score 0):

You should answer my question as I am not sure to fully ubderstand your issue.

Anyway, what you could try is :

- empty host
- empty port
- whole URL in path like http://www.example.com

Comment: Sorry for the delay,
My code consist in two request, in the first one, I receive a json response that I parse with a simple script to grab the url. The second request simply calls the url that I setted in a variable. At this moment it add the ending /

Answer (score 0):

I had to added a ? mark to the end of the url to make it work, you can try it.

If you have already has a ? mark, add a & mark instead.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I set  full URL in the 
field **Server Name or IP**.

You should set there only web domain name and 
in field **Path** set rest of URI...

[image: JMetter set URL]